# How to get attribute of moused over element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I am adding event listeners to an array of elements so that when the particular element is moused over it will set a property to the id of that element. However Instead of using the id of the element that is moused over it is selecting the last one that had the event listener added to it.

I guess my question is how can I grab the id of the moused over element?

Also note that I am using Vue and I tried using the `@mouseover` event however I guess because I am using it on a package `vue-pdf` it does not register the event?

```
   <pdf 
        v-for="i in numPages"
        :key="i"
        :page="i"
        :src="src"
        v-if="!loading"
        @num-pages="pageCount = $event"
        :ref="`${i}`"
        :id="`${i}`"
        @mouseover="setPage(i)"
    />
```

Anyway once the document is rendered I call this method

```
methods:{
addListener() {
  if(this.numPages > 0) {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.numPages; i++) {
       var span = this.$refs[i+1][0].$el

       //this is the area I am having issues with
       span.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {    
          this.currentPage = span.getAttribute('id')
        })


       }
    } else {
    console.log('didnt work')
  }
},
}

mounted() {
   this.addListener()
}
```

Also I have built a workaround using the `getBoundClientRect` but I feel like figuring out which element I am currently viewing should be easier than that.

Comment: readup on event delegation and propagation vs bubbling. `element.matches(strCSS)` is super-useful here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I had to also look at which is related to your problem is event bubbling and how to stop it

The problem I found is if there was a container with nested elements in that had sub events all three events were triggered 
[Event Bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing)

Other than that Using arrow functions for events sometimes leaves out important event information.

```
//----------------------------------^--
span.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {    

     // this.currentPage = span.getAttribute('id')
     let myEvent = e.target || e.currentTarget ;
     this.currentPage = myEvent.getAttribute('id') ;

     //Check out details of the event ....
     console.log(myEvent );
    })
```

The "e" is a reference to the event so "myEvent.getAttribute('id')" is what you are looking for .
In terms of bubbling Some Times you might be clicking on a child element nested inside of the element with the event which you can make a reference to **e.target.parent** or **e.target.parent.parent** to traverse through the DOM to get to the element details that hold's the event.

If you have nested elements that each have there own events say for example a div with an event then span separate event nested inside the div . You can stop the event from bubbling and triggering the div event with **e.stopPropagation();**

This means that when triggering the

> span

event the parent

> div

event wont be triggered

Comment: Hey thanks this solution worked great! I had to use `e.target.parent` for my situation. also instead of `myEvent.id` I still had to use `myEvent.getAttribute('id')`.